# Is Red Robin a Meta-Human?

Tags: dc, the-new-52

In Teen Titans #7 we see Red Robin saying this:

[image]

> We're fighting for all of them, all of **us.**

He is including himself in a group of meta-humans which the Teen Titans are trying to protect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Teen Titans #8 it is definitely stated by Omen that Red Robin is not a Meta-human.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Drake is not a meta-human, he's the retired side-kick to Batman.

His reference to "all of us" may refer to just super-hero teenagers as well as meta-humans. He says "us" because the people being targeted are part of the Teen Titans, and as such, an extension of Robin himself because they are all part of a team.